# Combining a semaphore with std::stop_token

Tags: c++, multithreading, semaphore

So I have some consumer, which is a seperate thread and waits on a semaphore. If the semaphore gets posted, it does some work and then goes back to waiting on the semaphore.

Because I want to be modern, I decided to use an std::jthread. Now I have this std::stop_token thing and my code looks like this:

```
void thread(std::stop_token stopToken)
{
    while(true) {
        bool success = this->sem.try_acquire_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        if (stopToken.stop_requested()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!success) {
            continue;
        }
        // Do the actual work
}
```

Somehow this feels way to clunky. It would be nice if I could wait on both the semaphore and the stoptoken. Or maybe modify jthread so that it will post the semaphore on destruction. Is something like that possible?

Comment: how you stop the thread in original method?

Comment: With the exact setup shown in the example.

Comment: If all your acquires of `sem` are guarded by the same stop token, you could have a stop_callback that calls `sem->release(N)`

Comment: @Artyer that works! Can you post this as an answer?